# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] docker compose

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose, containers

This is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  #PHP Service
    php:

        container_name: php
        build:
            context: .
            target: php
            args:
              - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
        environment:
            DB_HOST: database
            DB_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            DB_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
            DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
              - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
              - CONTAINER_ROLE=app
        working_dir: /var/www
        networks:
          - app
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
          - database
          # - redis

  #Database
    database:
        command: ['mysqld', '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
        container_name: database
        image: mysql
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        environment:
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
          - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        networks:
          - app
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    db-data: ~
```

when I am run the "sudo docker compose build --no-cache && sudo docker compose up --force-recreate -d"

and exec -it php bash and run php artisan migrate SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the environment to MYSQL and it's worked

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  #PHP Service
    php:

        container_name: php
        build:
            context: .
            target: php
            args:
              - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
        environment:
            MYSQL_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
              - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
              - CONTAINER_ROLE=app
        working_dir: /var/www
        networks:
          - app
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www
        ports:
          - 8000:8000
        links:
          - mysql
        depends_on:
          - mysql
          # - redis

  #Database
    mysql:
        command: ['mysqld', '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password']
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
        environment:
           - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='${DB_PASSWORD}'
           - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST= "%"
           - MYSQL_DATABASE= '${DB_DATABASE}'
           - MYSQL_USER= '${DB_USERNAME}'
           - MYSQL_PASSWORD= '${DB_PASSWORD}'
           - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD= 1
        networks:
          - app
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

    phpmyadmin:
      depends_on:
        - mysql
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      environment:
       - PMA_HOST=mysql
       - PMA_PORT=3306
      networks:
        - app
      ports:
        - 8001:80

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    db-data: ~
```